# Mapbox - filters override each other

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a map based on this example:
https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/finder-with-filters/

In their example, they have two dropdown filters and one checkbox filter. I would like to have three checkbox filters. I created three checkbox filters, and on their own, they seem to work well. The issue is that the filters seem to override each other in the order clicked. In their example, the filters seem to be working together, so I can't figure out why it's not working anymore when I changed the filter type.

Here's the code for my project:
https://codepen.io/flyinginsect2/pen/eYdyqxZ

Here are snippets of the code relevant to filtering:

```
const config = {
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoibGF1cmFqZWFudGhvcm5lIiwiYSI6ImNraXl5M29oMDEyMjgzM3BhNTh1MGc1NjkifQ.g4IAFIrXPpl3ricw3f_Onw",
    CSV: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/106xm254us29hAUEtR7mTo0hwbDJv8dhyQs9rxY601Oc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Attributes",
    center: [-104.339, 46.869],
    zoom: 2, 
    title: "ENVIROlocity Mapper",
    description: "Environmental Networking, Volunteering, Internship, and R.... Opportunities",
    sideBarInfo: ["Org_name", "CityState"],
    popupInfo: ["Org_name"],
    filters: [
        {
            type: "checkbox",
            title: "Sector: ",
            columnHeader: "Sector",
            listItems: ["Local Government", "Nonprofit"]
        },
        {
            type: "checkbox",
            title: "Industry: ",
            columnHeader: "Industry_type",
            listItems: ["Conservation", "Policy"]
        },
        {
            type: "checkbox",
            title: "Internships: ",
            columnHeader: "internships_YN",
            listItems: ["Yes"]
        }
    ]

};

const selectFilters = [];
const checkboxFilters = [];

function createFilterObject(filterSettings) {
    filterSettings.forEach(function (filter) {
        if (filter.type === 'checkbox') {
            columnHeader = filter.columnHeader;
            listItems = filter.listItems;

            const keyValues = {};
            Object.assign(keyValues, { header: columnHeader, value: listItems });
            checkboxFilters.push(keyValues);
        }
        if (filter.type === 'dropdown') {
            columnHeader = filter.columnHeader;
            listItems = filter.listItems;

            const keyValues = {};

            Object.assign(keyValues, { header: columnHeader, value: listItems });
            selectFilters.push(keyValues);
        }
    });
}

function applyFilters() {
    const filterForm = document.getElementById('filters');

    filterForm.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const filterOptionHTML = this.getElementsByClassName('filter-option');
        const filterOption = [].slice.call(filterOptionHTML);

        const geojSelectFilters = [];
        const geojCheckboxFilters = [];
        filteredFeatures = [];
        filteredGeojson.features = [];

        filterOption.forEach(function (filter) {
            if (filter.type === 'checkbox' && filter.checked) {
                checkboxFilters.forEach(function (objs) {
                    Object.entries(objs).forEach(function ([key, value]) {
                        if (value.includes(filter.value)) {
                            const geojFilter = [objs.header, filter.value];
                            geojCheckboxFilters.push(geojFilter);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            if (filter.type === 'select-one' && filter.value) {
                selectFilters.forEach(function (objs) {
                    Object.entries(objs).forEach(function ([key, value]) {
                        if (value.includes(filter.value)) {
                            const geojFilter = [objs.header, filter.value];
                            geojSelectFilters.push(geojFilter);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        if (geojCheckboxFilters.length === 0 && geojSelectFilters.length === 0) {
            geojsonData.features.forEach(function (feature) {
                filteredGeojson.features.push(feature);
            });
        } else if (geojCheckboxFilters.length > 0) {
            geojCheckboxFilters.forEach(function (filter) {
                geojsonData.features.forEach(function (feature) {
                    if (feature.properties[filter[0]].includes(filter[1])) {
                        if (
                            filteredGeojson.features.filter(
                                (f) => f.properties.id === feature.properties.id
                            ).length === 0
                        ) {
                            filteredGeojson.features.push(feature);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            if (geojSelectFilters.length > 0) {
                const removeIds = [];
                filteredGeojson.features.forEach(function (feature) {
                    let selected = true;
                    geojSelectFilters.forEach(function (filter) {
                        if (
                            feature.properties[filter[0]].indexOf(filter[1]) < 0 &&
                            selected === true
                        ) {
                            selected = false;
                            removeIds.push(feature.properties.id);
                        } else if (selected === false) {
                            removeIds.push(feature.properties.id);
                        }
                    });
                });
                removeIds.forEach(function (id) {
                    const idx = filteredGeojson.features.findIndex(
                        (f) => f.properties.id === id
                    );
                    filteredGeojson.features.splice(idx, 1);
                });
            }
        } else {
            geojsonData.features.forEach(function (feature) {
                let selected = true;
                geojSelectFilters.forEach(function (filter) {
                    if (
                        !feature.properties[filter[0]].includes(filter[1]) &&
                        selected === true
                    ) {
                        selected = false;
                    }
                });
                if (
                    selected === true &&
                    filteredGeojson.features.filter(
                        (f) => f.properties.id === feature.properties.id
                    ).length === 0
                ) {
                    filteredGeojson.features.push(feature);
                }
            });
        }

        map.getSource('locationData').setData(filteredGeojson);
        buildLocationList(filteredGeojson);
    });
}

function filters(filterSettings) {
    filterSettings.forEach(function (filter) {
        if (filter.type === 'checkbox') {
            buildCheckbox(filter.title, filter.listItems);
        } else if (filter.type === 'dropdown') {
            buildDropDownList(filter.title, filter.listItems);
        }
    });
}

function removeFilters() {
    let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    let selectOption = [].slice.call(select);
    let checkboxOption = [].slice.call(input);
    filteredGeojson.features = [];
    checkboxOption.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.type == 'checkbox' && checkbox.checked == true) {
            checkbox.checked = false;
        }
    });

    selectOption.forEach(function (option) {
        option.selectedIndex = 0;
    });

    map.getSource('locationData').setData(geojsonData);
    buildLocationList(geojsonData);
}

function removeFiltersButton() {
    const removeFilter = document.getElementById('removeFilters');
    removeFilter.addEventListener('click', function () {
        removeFilters();
    });
}

createFilterObject(config.filters);
applyFilters();
filters(config.filters);
removeFiltersButton();
```

I read this Mapbox documentation on combining filters, but I can't figure out how to work it in.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/other/#other-filter

I know there are many other Stack Exchange posts out there that address filtering on multiple criteria, but I can't find one that seems to address this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the space in value for `"Local Government"`

If you look at the generated HTML you will see a space in the `id`, which is not valid HTML

```
<input class="px12 filter-option" type="checkbox" id="Local Government" value="Local Government">
```

Just remove the whitespaces when building the HTML `id` attribute

```
input.setAttribute('id', listItems[i].replace(/\s/g,''));
```